# get value of a key from nested Json using JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to get the values of the below JSON string :

```
{
    "PaymentStatus": [
        {
            "MerchantTxnRefNo": "277753772122780",
            "PaymentId": "20239622798237",
            "ProcessDate": "9/16/2022 8:39:00 PM",
            "StatusDescription": "Transaction Success",
            "TrackId": "20239622798237",
            "BankRefNo": "20239622798237",
            "PaymentType": "CMA",
            "ErrorCode": "0",
            "ProductType": "DBO",
            "finalStatus": "success"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have used the below code to get it but did not work :

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", body, 
ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

var obj = response.Content;
var TransactionObj = JObject.Parse(obj);

var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(obj);
string StatusDescription = (string)jObject["PaymentStatus"]["StatusDescription"];
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What is `obj`? Is it just the JSON string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wold try something like this

```
var paymentStatus = JObject.Parse(response.Content)["PaymentStatus"][0];

string statusDescription = paymentStatus["StatusDescription"].ToString();

string merchantTxnRefNo = paymentStatus["MerchantTxnRefNo"].ToString();
```

or maybe you  need c# classes

```
List<PaymentStatus> paymentStatuses = JObject.Parse(json)["PaymentStatus"]
                                        .ToObject<List<PaymentStatus>>();

string statusDescription = paymentStatuses[0].StatusDescription;

long merchantTxnRefNo = paymentStatuses[0].MerchantTxnRefNo;

public class PaymentStatus
{
    public long MerchantTxnRefNo { get; set; }
    public long PaymentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProcessDate { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
    public long TrackId { get; set; }
    public long BankRefNo { get; set; }
    public string PaymentType { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public string finalStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PaymentStatus resolves to an array, use the indexer to get the object as below

var StatusDescription = (string)jObject["PaymentStatus"]`[0]`["MerchantTxnRefNo"];

Comment: it did not work also :(

Comment: @HAJJAJ I have updated my answer. Please try this.